# error: reserved word 'var' javascript/vue

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, vue.js

My mission is very simple: I just want an array with strings.
The background is that I want to put in barcodes in that array later on.

But the main problem right now is that I always get:

"index.vue: var is a reserved word"

I have looked into the vue doc and even tried the example.
But have no clue why I always get this syntax error.

So that is my javascript part, the interesting block is the last one where I want to declare my array.

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    import moment from 'moment';
    
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          form: {
            barcodes: [],
            id: this.$route.params.id,
            form: {},
            used_by: '',
            return_time: '',
            barcode: '',
            onSubmit: false,
          }
        }
      },
      methods: {
        onSubmit() {
          this.$message('submit!')
    
          axios.put('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tools/' + this.id, this.form)
          .then(response => {
              console.log(response);
              this.onSubmit = true;
          })
          .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
          })
        },
        onCancel() {
          this.$message({
            message: 'cancel!',
            type: 'warning'
          })
        }
      },
      
      created() {
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tools/' + this.id)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            this.form = response.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
      },
    
      var example2 = new Vue({
        el: '#example-2',
        data: {
          parentMessage: 'Parent',
          items: [
            { message: 'Foo' },
            { message: 'Bar' }
          ]
        }
      })
      
    }

</script>
```

This is the html part:

```
<ul id="example-2">
   <li v-for="(item, index) in items">
   {{ parentMessage }} - {{ index }} - {{ item.message }}
   </li>
</ul>
```

Here you can also see the example: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for

But I get:

```
index.vue: var is a reserved word (89:2)

  87 |   },
  88 |   
> 89 |   var example2 = new Vue({
     |   ^
  90 |   el: '#example-2',
  91 |   data: {
  92 |     parentMessage: 'Parent',
```

Comment: remove var keyword and it will work as expected

Comment: well you are in an object

Comment: because you cannot declare a property in a object with a var statement.

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini but this doesn't appear like a property since he is using `=` sign instead of `:`, i think is making a typo

Comment: in fact you cannot either use equal sign after a object key. It seems that you miss the javascript's basis

Comment: please share the content of `index.vue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a variable declaration inside an object literal. It should be written as an object property:

```
  example2: new Vue({
    el: '#example-2',
    data: {
      parentMessage: 'Parent',
      items: [
        { message: 'Foo' },
        { message: 'Bar' }
      ]
    }
  })
```

Comment: Ah okay, ya I got this. But even when I include my array in the existing data()-Block I still get "Property or method "items" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render."

Comment: That sounds specific to how Vue uses this data, and I don't know anything about that. I'm just helping you fix the generic JavaScript syntax.

Comment: Ok, solved it. I forgot the right Notation: form.items